# Same classes are referenced in both war and ejb Jar in Wildfly 10

Tags: jar, ejb, wildfly, war

I have some classes referenced in both Java Servlets and ejb Stateless Session Beans. I was wondering if I need to package the classes in both .war and ejb jar files.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the deployment type you want to choose.

If you need only a war deployment, then you can put your EJBs into a jar and put your "common" classes into a jar and put boths jars into the WEB-INF/lib.

If you want to use an ear deployment, you can put your common jar into the lib folder of the ear and define the jar with EJBs as module in the root of the ear. Next to the EJB jar you put your war and define it as web module.

Comment: This is pretty much on the money. If you actually need an EAR deployment you need to remember that classes in EJB jars and EAR/lib jars cannot see anything that is inside the WAR, such as classes,  property files andWEB-INF/lib jars. These days a single WAR containing everything is almost always a better solution.

Comment: That's an pretty old existing J2EE project. EAR is used to deploy. It is running fine in WLS8. Now it needs to migrate to Wildfly 10. I'll modify Ant build and try what you siom suggested. Thanks again